# R how to pass a function to a function

Tags: r, function, plm

When I want to specify my own robust standard errors in a regression command like plm, how do I do this directly without running several functions?

```
library("plm")
library("lmtest")
Data <- iris
Data$time <- as.numeric(rep(1951:2000,3))
```

here is what I would run in plm:

```
regression <- plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
    data = Data, 
    index = c("Species", "time"), 
    model = "within", 
    effect = "twoways")
```

now say I'd like a covariance matrix which clusters at the individual (species level):

```
results <- coeftest(regression,vcov=vcovHC(regression,type="HC0",cluster="group"))
```

My question is how I can include these standard errors directly in `plm` without having to run it first. This is not a big deal as the covariance matrix is calculated in a separate step anyways but would feel more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

In the plm-world, the covariance matrix is always passed as an additional argument, e.g. to `summary()`. But you can try the following:
In the plm object, overwrite the vcov that is already there:

`regression$vcov <- vcovHC(regression, type="HC0", cluster="group")`

But no guarantee this does not break anything else if you apply various functions to your plm object later.

You might also want to look at the `summary.plm` object created by `summary.plm`, e.g.

```
res <- summary(regression, vcov = vcovHC(regression, type="HC0", cluster="group"))
```

Also, you might want to look at `?summary.plm` (doc for summary.plm) how to pass the `vcov` function to `summary` (the example above passes the matrix the function creates).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a question about elegancy, try packages `dplyr`, (or `pipeR` or `magrittr`) for a 'pipe' operator. When writing `functionA(functionB((x)` or

```
y <- functionB(x)
z <- functionA(y)
```

you can use a great alternative as such:

```
z <- x %>% functionB %>% functionA
```

In your case, this would make:

```
results <- 
plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
    data = Data, 
    index = c("Species", "time"), 
    model = "within", 
    effect = "twoways") %>% 
coeftest(., vcov=vcovHC(.,type="HC0",cluster="group"))
```

in which you use `.` to explicitly mark that you're inputting what is before the `%>%` pipe operator.

Comment: Thats quite nice, thanks! (p.s.: typos in my question corrected, should also be Sepal.L(!)ength in your answer). The downside is that I only get the result of the second function in `results`, correct?

Comment: The problem with your answer is that I can't use this version inside another command where plm is an argument. Do you know how I can include the covariance matrix inside plm? Your code does one after the other